# Creating a json-style inside a linq select statement

Tags: c#, json, linq

In my MVC controller, I have the following linq query (which works fine):

```
var result = from li in lineItems
             join r in rates on li.something = r.something
             select new
             {
                 li.something
                 li.somethingElse
                 li.another
                 r.something
                 r.somethingElse
                 r.rate1
                 r.rate2
                 r.rate3
                 r.rate4
             };

return JSON(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And that generates a flat object just fine. However, what I really need is for the rates to be an object of their own, one layer deeper, like this:

```
{
    li.something
    li.somethingElse
    li.another
    r.something
    r.somethingElse
    rates = {
                {id = "1", value = r.rate1}
                {id = "2", value = r.rate2}
                {id = "3", value = r.rate3}
                {id = "4", value = r.rate4}
            }
}
```

I'm having difficulty getting the C# syntax right to make that happen. Hardcoding the id is fine. I will always only have rate 1 2 3 and 4.

Comment: You can define 'rates' property as anonymous array of object.

Answer (score 3):

You can define 'rates' property as anonymous array of object, please see below sample for reference.

```
{
    li.something,
    li.somethingElse,
    li.another,
    r.something,
    r.somethingElse,
    rates = new[]{
                new {id = "1", value = r.rate1},
                new {id = "2", value = r.rate2},
                new {id = "3", value = r.rate3},
                new {id = "4", value = r.rate4}
            }
}
```

Comment: This compiles, but throws a runtime error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

{"The array type '<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]][]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]' instead."}

Comment: What are datatypes of 'r.rate1' and so on?

Comment: They are all type decimal.

Comment: It's a weird problem, I have tried this in console and it's working with decimal and decimal? type. I am bit curious know more about the problem. Could you please share details such as framework version, any database query going on and what is source of lineitems object?

Comment: EF Framework (EF6). lineItems is an IQueryable<LineItem> and rates is IQueryable<Rate>.

Comment: If you are using EF6 then better if you fetch data as earlier approach and form the JSON object in memory the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
rates = new
{
    Rate1 = new {id = "1", value = r.rate1}
    Rate2 = new {id = "2", value = r.rate2}
    Rate3 = new {id = "3", value = r.rate3}
    Rate4 = new {id = "4", value = r.rate4}
}
```

Which didn't throw any errors. It named the JSON which I didn't really need but I guess it didn't hurt anything either.